# Making a listing of quotes

Tags: tocloft, csquotes

I have a use case in which I need to list all the inline quotes used in a journalistic type article at the end along with attribution. Something like:

START EXAMPLE
Text text text "this is a quote," said person1. Text text text "and this is another," according to person2. ...

**List of quotes:**

"this is a quote"
         Person1, Title, Organization

"and this is another"
         Person2, Title, Organization

END EXAMPLE

I'm very new to Latex and not clear on the best approach. I made a quick botch of trying to get tocloft to work with one of the csquote commands (\textquote), based on examples I found online. Is this a feasible approach or are there other recommended approaches that would be sounder?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Indeed, your question is not really clear. Can you show your use case as a starter?

Comment: Yes, the use case is to be able to list all the inline quotes in a document, along with attribution, So if a document has 6 "quotes like this one", and like "this one", then it would be possible to produce a "List of quotes", with attributions to the speakers, similar to lists of equations, figures, etc.

Comment: No, I meant your TeX document.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be better to approach the problem in a similar style to citations. First define a set of quotes (just like you'd define a set of citations in a `.bib` file) and then use the ones you want in the document.

Here's an example using the [`glossaries`](http://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries) package. The quotes are defined using the custom `\newquote` command that this example provides. To keep the example simple, I've just put them in the preamble, but if you have a lot of them, it's easier to put them in a separate `.tex` file (called, say, `quotes.tex`) and them load that file using `\loadglsentries{quotes}`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\makenoidxglossaries

% \newquote[options]{label}{name}{quote}{title}{organisation}
\newcommand*{\newquote}[6][]{%
 \newglossaryentry{#2}{name={#3},description={#4},%
    user1={#5},user2={#6},#1}%
}

% \usequote{label}{said}
\newcommand*{\usequote}[2]{\enquote{\glsdesc{#1},} #2 \glstext{#1}}

% Convert the first letter of the quote to upper case:
\newcommand*{\Usequote}[2]{\enquote{\Glsdesc{#1},} #2 \glstext{#1}}

\newglossarystyle{quotes}{%
  \setglossarystyle{index}%
  \renewcommand*{\glossentry}[2]{%
    \item\glsentryitem{##1}\glstarget{##1}{\enquote{\Glossentrydesc{##1}}}
    \glossentryname{##1}, \glsentryuseri{##1}, \glsentryuserii{##1}%
  }%
}
\newcommand*{\printquotes}[1][]{%
 \printnoidxglossary[sort=use,nogroupskip,style=quotes,%
   title={List of Quotes},#1]%
}

\newquote{smith1}{John Smith}{this is a quote}{President}{Smith \& co}
\newquote{doe1}{Jane Doe}{and this is another}{Galactic Ruler}{The Empire}
\newquote{smith2}{John Smith}{we retract our earlier statement}{President}{Smith \& co}

\begin{document}
Text text text \usequote{smith1}{said}.
Text text text \usequote{doe1}{according to}.
\Usequote{smith2}{said}.

\printquotes
\end{document}
```

As with tables of contents, cross-references etc this requires two runs to ensure the document is up to date. I'm assuming that you want the quotes listed according to the order of use in the document. I've used `\enquote` instead of `\textquote` for simplicity, but you can adapt it as required.

The resulting document looks like:

[image: image of document]

Comment: Thank you very much for this example. I had found the glossaries package since my original post and come to the same conclusion. I made one minor modification to the style because I need the long form on the first usage, and just the surname after that. John Smith, President, Smith & co said "this is a quote".  "We retract our earlier statement," exclaimed Smith.